# Special Characters in TWIML verb

Tags: xml, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I have a  verb I need to read in spanish.  However, the Twilio .Net parser is failing with Invalid character in the given encoding.  The line that's failing (edited for brevity) is:

```
> <Say voice="man" language="es">cita para la instalación de alfombra,
> el lunes, 15 de enero</Say>
```

My XML is defined as `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

How can I make the Twilio .Net library parse that character correctly?  If I put this directly in a TWIML bin it works, however, the .Net SDK doesn't parse it.

Updated: Adding code examples

I'm using the helper library to generate VoiceResponse objects and returning them through the webhook. For example:

```
foreach (var (translation, date) in installations)
{
    gather.Append(new Say($"{translation} {SpanishDate(date)}", Say.VoiceEnum.Man, language: "es"));
}
public static string SpanishDate(DateTime date)
{
return $"el {date.ToString("dddd", new CultureInfo("es-ES"))}, {(date.Day == 1 ? "primo" : date.Day.ToString())} de {date.ToString("MMMM", new CultureInfo("es-ES"))}";
}
```

I'm looking at the resulting XML that gets returned by the helper library, which is:

```
<Say voice="man" language="es">Cita para la instalacion de pisos de madera  el miércoles, 28 de febrero</Say>
```

The XML that's generated by the VoiceResponse object (using the ToString() method) is stored in blob storage until the call is placed, then returned as a TwiMLResult in the webhook.

The exception is being thrown in the helper library's TwiMLResult constructor, which is attempting to parse the XML and is failing.

```
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e) 
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.InvalidCharRecovery(Int32& bytesCount, Int32& charsCount) 
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.GetChars(Int32 maxCharsCount) 
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ReadData() 
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText(Int32& startPos, Int32& endPos, Int32& outOrChars) 
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishPartialValue() 
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.get_Value() 
at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r) 
at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r, LoadOptions o) 
at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options) 
at Twilio.AspNet.Mvc.TwiMLResult.LoadFromString(String twiml, Encoding encoding) 
at Twilio.AspNet.Mvc.TwiMLResult..ctor(String twiml)
```

Comment: the sdk libraries do not parse twiml , they generate twiml. As a side note , always post code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at how @Marcos did his sample, I found that when I return the pre-rendered XML in the TwiMLResult, I wasn't setting the encoding there to UTF8.  The proper way to do it is (example):

```
var xml = voiceResponse.ToString();
var result = new TwiMLResult(xml, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Looking at the example you posted, it doesn't look like you are generating TwiML by using the helper library you can find [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Twilio). You can install it by running:

`Install-Package Twilio`

I wrote a sample application using the same string as you are and got the correct XML to be generated.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{       
    var response = new VoiceResponse();
    response.Say("cita para la instalación de alfombra, el lunes, 15 de enero!", language: "es");

    return Content(response.ToString(), "text/xml");
}
```

The above returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
  <Say language="es">cita para la instalación de alfombra, el lunes, 15 de enero!</Say>
</Response>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I updated my question to show how I'm using the helper library, your example doesn't use the TwiML result object, which I think is the culprit of the exception.